# How to view a reported error in Google Chrome DevTools while debugging an MVC 5 app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an MVC 5 application using Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to use Chrome to debug the JQuery and other such things in my application.  Chrome is reporting several errors as I run my MVC app through Visual Studio.  The errors in Chrome are shown as follows:

[image]

I have tried right and left clicking on the error icons but there is nothing I see where Chrome will take you to the location of the errors it is reporting.  I have clicked on several of the Chrome menu bar choices such as Elements, Console, and source but nothing shows what the errors are.

I have the following options selected in Visual Studio 2017:

[image]

I am more familiar with using Visual Studio for debugging problems but I know very little using Chrome. Is there a window in Chrome I should be using similar the one in Visual Studio which shows all errors in a single window? A window where I can click on the reported error and it will take me to the page with the error and highlight it? How do I find the location of those errors Chrome says exist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The errors will show in the console. In Chrome press F12 to open it, then press ESC to toggle the console open/closed. Alternatively, open dev tools, then click on the 'console' tab. Also, IMO, disable the JS debugging features in VS. They are clunky, slow and worse than what's available in the browser natively.

Comment: Disabling the Visual Studio debugger options for Chrome fixed the problem. Chrome is now giving me more information. Thanks.